# Adverbs and adverbials

Tags: adverbs

I am really confused on the this topic, could someone please help? In a phrase like,"Come on up." I know "up" modifies "come on." What happens when you are able to switch positions of adverbs and adverbials? In, "I played yesterday at the park.", and "I played at the park yesterday." Does "yesterday" modify "played at the park" in both or does "at the park" modify played yesterday in the first sentence?

Comment: I'd say that the preposition "up" is complement of "on", not modifier, of "come on". In your other examples, the pronoun "yesterday" and the PP "at the park" are distinct adjuncts in clause structure, i.e. they are both modifiers of the VP.

Comment: The usual order of adverbials is manner, place, time. "I played at the park yesterday" is therefore unsurprising, and in speech your intonation would convey information about the component you wished to highlight. "I played yesterday at the park", on the other hand, departs from standard usage and in so doing draws attention to itself. You can imagine this word order being used, for example, in an antagonistic context (an objection from bookish a child who is being chided for not playing enough?)